# How to work with refresh token in DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi, refresh-token

I am using docusign authentication flow as

On Sign In
let url = "https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=token&scope=signature extended&client_id=39b5f6fb-97ca-XXXXXXXXXXXXX&state=a39fh23hnf23XXXXX&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/callbackdocusign";

window.open(url, '_self');
after successfully validating it return access_token/expires_in/token_type/state.

please guide how to get refresh_token?
after refresh_token how to obtain new access_token?

For refresh_token I tried as
let url = "https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=refresh_token&scope=signature extended&client_id=39b5f6fb-97ca-XXXXXXXXXXXXX&state=a39fh23hnf23XXXXX&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/callbackdocusign";
window.open(url, '_self');

But it is not returning refresh_token

Answer (score 0):

The URL you are using has `response_type=token`. This response type is used for Implicit grant authentication and it does not support refresh tokens. If you need a refresh token you have to use Authorization Code Grant. Your URL would look like this

```
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature extended&client_id=39b5f6fb-97ca-XXXXXXXXXXXXX&state=a39fh23hnf23XXXXX&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/callbackdocusign
```

This will provide a "code" parameter in the URL when your user is redirected after authenticating. You can use that code to get the actual access and refresh tokens.

You can find the full explanation here:
https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/authcode-get-token/

Answer (score 0):

You're currently using the Implicit grant flow. It does not provide a refresh token.

Refresh tokens are only provided with the Authorization Code grant flow.

If you're initiating the OAuth flow from the browser (using React, etc), then you cannot use Authorization Code grant flow at this time since it requires the secure storage of a client ID secret.

Comment: Now I am using Authorization Code grant flow with SPA in angular and all is working fine, but now I want to use that access_token or refresh_token for next 30 days, How I can manage this? even I used signature extended

Comment: And I am also getting error in viewing that document 
error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse 
message: "Http failure during parsing for https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/xxxxxxxxxxxxx-850d-c9d4af880e5a/envelopes/xxxxxxxxxx-aa28-c180415e7656/documents/1"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxd-c9d4af880e5a/envelopes/xxxxxxxxxxxx-aa28-c180415e7656/documents/1"

Comment: Please open a new question on StackOverflow. As noted above, only Implicit grant is supported for SPA applications. This is due to the OAuth RFCs that do not allow secrets to be stored in angular or similar applications.